# NetBeans and glassFish server

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I've a problem with the glassFish server they show me this message when I deploy a project :

> build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.

I'been restart netbeans any times and change debugmode to TRUE but the problem continue.

It's the line 1045 by build-impl.xml:

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

I use:

- macOS Sierra 10.12
- NetBeans 8.2
- GlassFish 4.1.1
- JDK 8

Answer (score 0):

Try undeploying your project (In NetBeans 8.2 go to Services, Servers, GlassFish Server, right click on your deployed project and click 'undeploy'. Then restart GlassFish and run your project (after Clean and Build). That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this before. I did the following:

1. Removed pom.xml and nb.configuration files from my project.
2. Ensured that I had added the correct project type.
3. Built and ran my client.

My server built successfully.